# prestashop accessing the my-account link is unavilable

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to access ayushho.com/my-account and getting the error message called "This page is not available". I have just installed a new SSL certificate and certifate checcker confirmed that SSL installation is correct.

Friendly URL set to Yes. and Shop Domain and SSL domain name set to ayushho.com and https://ayushho.com.

Why i am not able to access any other page apart from main page.

Comment: You do not need to set "https://" for SSL domain, just ayushho.com

Comment: That resolves the issue. Thanks for your help.